# Is it possible to run code analysis of .NetCore1.1 projects with SonarQube?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, .net-core

I've been trying to run code analysis of several .Net Core 1.1 projects, but have failed to get any results.

While using VS2015 and the project.json format I successfully sent the command:

**../Sonar/tools/sonar-scanner-2.8/bin/sonar-scanner**

and the sonar server shows each of the files in project(s) and test projects(s), but no analysis has actually been carried out:

- Lines of code = 0
- Vulnerabilities = 0
- code smells = 0

Having migrated the projects to VS2017 and the csproj format, I can't even get the scan to run.

Running in the main project folder:

**SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"Car.Enquiry-Presenter" /n:"Car.Enquiry-Presenter" /v:"1.0"** (no prolems here)
**msbuild Car.EnquiryPresenter.csproj**

throws error: "error MSB4066: The attribute "Version" in element  is unrecognized."

I can see here that the dotnet cli is not yet supported
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-310

But this post suggests that it is possible:
https://www.sonarsource.com/resources/product-news/news.html#2017-04-13-sonarqube-scanner-for-msbuild-2-3-released

'support for .NET Core projects: SONARMSBRU-167'

But I've been unable to get this to work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you have read through the documentation?

Comment: Also, which version of MSBuild is building your application

Comment: @CodeWarrior Yes, I've been through it.

Comment: @CodeWarrior I'm using MSBuild v15

Comment: Have also tried using v14 with the same results

Comment: Ok, have you tried their sample projects and see if you can reproduce the issue or not?

Comment: scratch that, their github links go to a 404

Comment: I think this might be your best bet https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf58/getting-help-and-support-771893129.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is the answer (great, I get to answer my own question!).

I've just got it working using v15 of MSBuild, but I needed to fully qlaulify the path to the exe, otherwise it continued to use v14:

- MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /key:"Car.Enquiry-Presenter" /name:"Car.Enquiry-Presenter" /version:"1.0"
- "../../../../Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe"
- MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end

I also needed to add a 'ProjectGuid' node to my csproj file containing a guid (i just generated that with https://www.guidgen.com/)

NB: Overriding the toolset you use in the csproj file does not force it to use v15. ie:  ... .
Hence the fully qualified path.

you need to ensure that the nuget packages are updated using a "dotnet restore" before calling msbuild.exe too.